# Displaying image on tooltip?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I would like to display an image on a tool tip.

How can I do this? Can you help me, or provide me with any references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using jQuery like so:

```
$("#img_id_here").hover(function()
{
    $(this).css('width', '400px');
});

<img src="whatever" onMouseOver="this.style.width='200px'" />
```

and in your CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .img:hover /* you should apply img class to your image. */
    {
        width:400px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Mr.Muhammad Akhtar it is good i want some additional requirements it is applicable for image control only right when i place link button the tooltip image is not working for link button. when i place the tool tip on the image the tooltip coming but when i remove the mouse it is not comeback to it's orginal size

Comment: when i apply for link button like this....

<asp:LinkButton  ID="text" runat ="Server" Text ="sasi" onMouseOver="this.style.width='200px'" ></asp:LinkButton>
it is not working giving jvascript error

Answer (score 2):

Refer the below link for displaying the images in tooltip.

http://www.dyn-web.com/code/tooltips/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's impossible with simple `title` attribute. You have to use something like [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip).

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the [jQuery Tooltip plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip)? That's where I'd start... :)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below link for showing images in tool tip.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/A_Simple_Tooltip.aspx